# Can perpetual machines be made?

Tags: thermodynamics, perpetual-motion

Nowadays there is a lot of questions regarding [perpetual motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion) and perpetual machines. So, can we make one? i searched a lot but i am am still not satisfied with the answers and with thermodynamics.

Comment: Per the Noether theorem, energy is in symmetry with time. Energy is released where time moves slower, which is in gravity. So gravity is the only possible "free" source to get energy without burning anything. We already harvest gravitational energy in hydro power plants. Then of course the solar energy restores the water balance.

Comment: The fundamental obstacle to the concept of perpetual motion is the *Law of Conservation of Energy*.  What is it about that law that you don't agree with or understand?

Comment: @OscarBravo Energy conservation is not absolute. Broadly speaking, energy in General Relativity is not conserved. More specifically, energy conservation is a consequence of the time symmetry per the Noether theorem. So energy is not conserved wherever time is not uniform, such as in gravitational time dilation or space expansion of the universe.

Comment: 'Searching a lot' is not the answer: instead learn the physics and you will understand why such things are not possible and what it would take for them to be possible.

Comment: @safesphere At the level of the OP's question a discussion of conservation of energy is perfectly adequate.

Answer (score -1):

The universe is about as close as we come to a perpetual motion machine. You can never say never but You would need to totally change the laws of physics as we know them to come up with an example of perpetual motion.

Comment: Does the downvoter have an example of perpetual motion? I think not!

Comment: Does that mean the Universe will go on forever.